# Adding an explicit non- "null" default value to parameters in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-web

this is Antika. I have started learning to code since a few days back, and am only familiar with HTML/CSS/JS, and basics of **dart/flutter**

**Developer Level:** Beginner

**Project type & language:** I'm developing a **Tasks App**, using **flutter**.

**THIS IS MY CODE FOR THE TASKS CARD (WIDGET)-**

```dart
class TaskCardWidget extends StatelessWidget {

//const TaskCardWidget({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

final String title;  
TaskCardWidget({this.title}); 

//  THE ERROR IS RETURNING HERE, IN THE LINE JUST ABOVE <<
//   ⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀⁀

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
  
...
// I WANT IT TO WORK LIKE THIS - 
// if title comes null,
// it should change to "Unnamed Task" 

          Text(
            title ?? "(Unnamed Task)",
           //style: TextStyle(),
          ),
...

    );}}
```

**PROBLEM/ERROR** - The code is returning this error below.

```
The parameter 'title' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.

Try adding an explicit non- "null" default value ...
```

**LIMITATION** - The limitation of the App is, it might get null values for `title`.
If it happens, I want to simply change the `title` value to "(Unnamed task)".

**HOW DO I GET THE CONSTRUCTOR TO ACCEPT THE 'title' VALUE AS IT IS**
 **AND DEAL WITH 'null' VALUE LATER IN CODE**

Comment: You can write `final String? title` to make `title` a nullable variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
final String title;
```

to

```
final String? title;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ravi Patel, This is exactly what I needed. ❤️

Comment: perfect only the ? need to be added to variable datatype

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is a working workaround, it is a wrong answer to a given question.

The default parameter value for a final field:

```
final String title;  
TaskCardWidget({this.title = "(Unnamed Task)"});
```